# Knockoutjs Error: Unable to parse bindings on Android 2.3

Tags: jquery-mobile, knockout.js, android-2.3-gingerbread

I have a knockoutjs template with the following code:

```
<script type="text/html" id="task-template">
  <li>
    <input type="checkbox" data-bind="attr: { id:$data.id, name: $data.id }, checked:checked" class="custom" />
    <label data-bind="attr: { for: $data.id }, text: displayText"></label>
  </li>
</script>
```

It runs successfully in most browsers. However, on Android 2.3.3, the template fails to render properly (i'm using jquerymobile). I get the following error from LogCat on my emulator:

```
02-15 21:53:05.915: E/browser(293): Bindings value: attr: { for: $data.id }, text: displayText http://(mySite)/js/knockout-2.0.0.js:6
```

Any ideas? I find this particularly frustrating since it works almost everywhere besides Android 2.3.3

Comment: If I was trying to narrow it down, I would first try putting 'for' in quotes.  Then, I would try creating an object on your view model that contains `{ for: id }` (like `viewModel.forBinding = { for: viewModel.id };` and do `attr: forBinding`.  Just a couple things to try to narrow down why it is having a problem with the syntax.

Answer (score 3):

Mr. Niemeyer's hunch was correct. I changed `{for: $data.id}` to `{'for': $data.id}` and all is well in Android 2.3.3 land. Thanks.